# setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints : Cannot call value of non-function type Bool

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system) as UIButton
button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

But Xcode (9.4) complains that

> Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints'

Answer (score 0):

Had to change it to the following for Swift4 (Xcode 9.4) :

```
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```